# How to track the use of a named/enchanted item using a scoreboard (or otherwise) in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a datapack for a "Fire Wand" (which is a carrot on a stick enchanted with Flame until they fix the stat tracker for shield usage) which spawns a fireball at the players position and [uses an aoe cloud](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2916120-1-13-how-to-summon-an-arrow-the-moves-in-the) spawned at the origin to give it momentum in the direction the player looks. I've got most of it working, however I also want to have several other behaviors (in other datapacks), also triggered by differently named and enchanted carrots on sticks, so I need to track not the simple use of a carrot on a stick but the use of a specifically named and enchanted one. If this isn't possible, is there a way to check for the item currently in the player's hand to make sure it is the correct function being run?

Comment: Yes, you have to check for the item in the hand. Since both happens in the same game tick, it's also 100% reliable, because the player can't switch away between the two checks. I'll look for a duplicate target…

Comment: Ok thanks! So if I use this command from IronAnvil's answer does the enchantment command go next to the id nbt?
`code` 
/testfor @s {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}
`code`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with "enchantment command", but if you're asking whether you can test for both enchantment and name at once, yes, you can. Remember to test for the exact number types and to check the brackets.

Comment: Sorry I meant enchantment specifier. I'm guessing that's a yes though.